# Is it possible to change the default value of a primitive data type?

Tags: c#, generics, list, struct, value-type

I recently created a generic Matrix<T> class that acts as a wrapper around a List<List<T>> collection. As far as I can tell, this class is working perfectly. I am running into a slight problem though regarding the default values of the T's.

I create an instance of Matrix<int>(3, 3), which creates a 3x3 matrix of ints, all defaulted to 0 using default(T). I know that value types (which include primitives) default to a 0 equivalent, and reference types default to null. I was wondering if it was possible to change this default value so that if a value type is passed into the Matrix, it would be populated with 5's for example, instead of 0's.

I tried creating my own struct (value type), but due to not being able to use parameterless constructors inside structs, I cannot find a way to change the default value from 0.

I suspect changing the default value is not possible, and I will have to loop through the Matrix cell by cell after it has been instantiated, but I wanted to ask on here just in case before I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 public Matrix(int width, int height) : this(width, height, default(T)) {}
 public Matrix(int width, int height, T defaultValue)
 {
     List<T> rows = new List<T>(height);
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         List<T> columns = new List<T>(width);
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         { columns.Add(defaultValue); }
         rows.Add(columns);
     }
     // store `rows` wherever you are storing it internally.
 }
```

But as Joseph says, there's no way of setting what `default(T)` evaluates to.

Comment: I didn't think of adding a constructor to define the default value. While not quite was I was looking for, it is quite nifty, and will definitely work!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to change the default value like how you're describing.

```
var someInt = default(int); //this will always be 0, you can't change it
var someReference = default(SomeClass); //this will always be null
```

Here's an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(VS.80).aspx) on it, although it's not much more descriptive than what's already been said unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the implementation of `default(T)` is that the runtime, by default, zeros out the memory as the application requests it, and C# just allocates the space without ever overwriting the zeros.  It just so happens that the default values of non-numeric types (e.g. the null reference, false) are represented as zeros in memory.  This can lead to some weird behavior; for example, `default(MyEnumType)` will be zero even if you never specified an enum value to be equal to zero.

Comment: `null` for reference types seems a good initialization value but a _common_ value for a value type is not so safe. I'd have preferred you couldn't use uninitialized variables at all. And this is implemented with local variables but not with fields. Or at least `default`ing to `MaxValue`. Of course, best solution would be to be able to define default values in project.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a structure that encapsulates it's value and only exposes it with an offset of the default value that you want:

```
public struct DefaultFiveInteger {

   private int _value;

   public DefaultFiveInteger(int value) {
      _value = x - 5;
   }

   public static implicit operator int(DefaultFiveInteger x) {
      return x._value + 5;
   }

   public static implicit operator DefaultFiveInteger(int x) {
      return new DefaultFiveInteger(x);
   }

}
```

Now you can declare a variable that is initialised to the default value (0), and it will return the value with the offset:

```
DefaultFiveInteger x;
Console.Write(x);
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Minor note: If one uses exclusive-or rather than addition, the code will work for all integer values even in a checked numeric context.  Additionally, it may be helpful to include am `int Value` get/set property, since type inference isn't sufficient to let one do everything with a `DefaultFiveInteger` that one can do with an `int` (e.g. if one had a `DefaultFiveInteger d5` and a `DefaultSixInteger d6`, one could say `d6 = (int)d5`, but it might be cleaner to say `d6.Value = d5.Value;`

Comment: @supercat: Good point on the checked context, that might be preferrable eventhough it's less intuitive how the values are stored. Having a setter for the value may cause problems (mutable structs are generally frowned upon), but an int getter might be useful.

Comment: Ancient dialects of C# would allow one to invoke property setters on structures in read-only contexts, even though such operations are usually nonsensical.  Back when such usage was allowed, that was a good argument against writing property setters which modified the underlying structure.  Unless one is targeting really old versions of C#, however, I don't think that argument is nearly as applicable [btw, I wonder why the makers of C# felt they had to "always" or "never" allow property setters and methods on read-only structures, rather than defining attributes to say what should be allowed?]

Comment: @supercat: The compiler protects you from trying to change a struct where it doesn't work, but it doesn't protect you from anything that can happen when it works. If it's used as a Dictionary key for example, changing the value will make the item unaccessible.

Comment: If a struct is used as a dictionary key, the only way to change the copy stored in the dictionary would be to remove it and re-add it (in which case it would work just fine).  Structs work better than mutable classes in that regard.  My complaint is that there's no way for e.g. struct `Drawing.Point` to specify that its `Offset` method modifies `this` and the compiler should not allow its invocation on a read-only structure.  Mutable structs could be a lot safer and more useful if an attribute were defined for such purpose.

Comment: @supercat: Right, in that case you are protected by the implementation of the dictionary, but you get the point? Or as Micrsoft puts it: "DO NOT define mutable value types." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031.aspx/css

Comment: Such advice is inappropriate for types whose purpose is to encapsulate multiple related but independent values (such as the coordinates of a point).  The design of many of the structures in things like XNA suggests that Microsoft has come to realize that many such things are best resented by exposed-field structures (which is how those types are defined).

Comment: @supercat: To have multiple values is also something that goes against the guidelines for value types. Just because Microsoft themselves goes against their own guidelines sometimes doesn't mean that the guidelines are wrong.

Comment: There are two main usage cases for value-types. The guidelines are designed for value-types which represent a single unified value. The other usage case, though, is the representation of a fixed combination of related but independent variables, and for that an exposed-field structure, which *is* a fixed combination of related but independent variables, is a perfect fit. Mutable classes are semantically wrong, and both immutable classes and so-called "immutable" structures are often unwieldy. The fact that screwdrivers aren't very good at pounding nails doesn't mean one should avoid using them.

Comment: @supercat: Generally you should use a class as data container, not a struct. The recommended maximum size of 16 bytes limits structs to very small containers anyway.

Comment: Those guidelines, including the 16-byte "rule", are only applicable to things that represent a unified value; even the 16 byte rule only applies to things that will be copied often. For things which represent related values that may need to be modified independently, the performance advantage of properly-used exposed-field structs over other types that are not piecewise modifiable *increases with size* until they get large enough to threaten the stack. Structs can't do anything, but mutable classes have many pitfalls which mutable structs avoid. A variable of...

Comment: It's the other way around. Mutable strucs have many pitfalls that mutable classes avoid.

Comment: ...a mutable data-holding class type may either encapsulate values in an exclusively-owned instance which it can change but which to it must not share a reference, or in a shared instance which it may share with code that won't modify it, but which it must never change. If a variable is used to encapsulates values and one wants to either change one or make the values contained therein available to outside code, one must know whether the first or second scenario applies. By contrast, a variable of an exposed field struct type always encapsulates only the values of its fields.

Comment: Suppose a `GameObject` class has a `CurrentPosition` property of a mutable class type (with members X, Y, and Z); an object wishes to set its position to match that of another, and later decrease its Z position by 2.  What must one know to determine whether the correct pattern would be something like `obj1.CurrentPosition = obj2.CurrentPosition.Clone(); ... obj1.CurrentPosition.Z -= 2;` or `obj1.CurrentPosition = obj2.CurrentPosition; ... var temp = obj1.CurrentPosition; obj1.CurrentPosition = new Location(temp.X, temp.Y, temp.Z-2);`? Guessing wrong may cause bizarre intermittent failures.

Comment: @supercat: Your example doesn't have anything to do with pitfalls of class vs. structs, it's just a matter of picking the implementation that fits the purpose. If the position should act as a single value, it should simply be immutable regardless of whether it's a struct or a class, and then it's not a problem. Besides, this discussion is pretty way off topic, as the struct in question shouldn't be mutable regardless of your opinion on using structs as data containers.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you're looking at structs already, you could simulate a default value as follows:

```
public struct MyInt
{
    private int _defaultInt;
    public int DefaultInt
    {
        get
        {
            if (_defaultInt == 0)
                return 5;
            else
                return _defaultInt;
        }
        set
        {
            _defaultInt = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This breaks if you set the int explicitly to 0. Your code will still return 5.

Comment: True, were I to implement it I would actually use an int? data type and check for null.  If it's null, you can assume it was never set, so return 5.

Answer (score 0):

Combining Guffa's and DougJones ideas you could offset a properties backing member.

```
public struct MyInt
{
    private const int INT_DEFAULT = 5;
    private int _defaultInt;
    public int DefaultInt
    {
        get { return _defaultInt + INT_DEFAULT; }
        set { _defaultInt = value - INT_DEFAULT; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you could use `MyInt&lt;T&gt; where T:IIntDefaultSupplier,new()`, where IIntDefaultReporter contains a `GetDefaultValue()` method.  The `MyInt&lt;T&gt;` class would contain a static default value, which would be loaded on first use by creating a new instance of `T` and calling `GetDefaultValue()` on it.  Also, I'd suggesting using xor rather than +/- so that you avoid integer overflow issues.